# Ubuntu 12.04: ld cannot find library

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, ld

I'm trying to compile Caffe (http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html) and I get the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latlas
```

However, I have these libraries installed (libatlas).
My LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains the path /usr/lib/atlas-base and it contains the files libcblas.so and libatlas.so (and some other files as well).

Why ld can't find these libraries?
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**tl;dr:** `Caffe` makefile looks for `libblas.so` in `/usr/lib`. If missing, `update-alternatives` creates a symbolic link `/usr/lib/libblas.so` to the location where it is installed. Same applies to `libcblas.so`. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for runtime, and doesn't have anything to do with this.

---

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` doesn't really help you when compiling. It only provides directories to look for shared libraries when executing programs that rely on them, *after* they are compiled. Still, when linking during the compilation, the compiler needs to find these shared libraries, and does so by other means than `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

More to the point: if compiling with `gcc` or `clang`, the directories in which to look for libraries to link with are provided using the `-L` flag, and it does not consider the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Common locations for `libblas.so` are `/usr/lib/atlas-base/` and `/usr/lib/libblas/`. The `Makefile` for `caffe` doesn't do anything particular to try and locate these subdirectories, and relies on these libraries being in the default library directory `/usr/lib/`. Typically a symbolic link `/usr/lib/libblas.so` exists, and points to the real location of the shared library. For some reason, this wasn't the case in your initial configuration.

When dealing with multiple alternatives for packages, `update-alternatives` comes in handy. In the case of `libblas.so` it let's you easily switch between multiple implementations (`libblas`, `openblas`) you might have installed, and does so by changing out the symbolic links.

`sudo update-alternatives --config libblas.so` created this symbolic link when it was missing, which in turn let the compiler find the shared library, solving your problem. This is indicated by the output of the command:

```
 $ sudo update-alternatives --config libblas.so
There is only one alternative in link group libblas.so (providing /usr/lib/libblas.so): /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so
Nothing to configure.
```

Same kind of reasoning applies to `libcblas.so`.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out I had to run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config libblas.so
sudo update-alternatives --config liblapack.so
```

and to select libatlas .
I have no idea why,. If anyone can explain this me I will give him the answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev` worked for me, it removed both missing dependencies.

See this thread for additional details https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/559

Answer (score 4):

As an addendum to @Ran's answer, Ubuntu in particular has an odd package structure for what's needed with Caffe. I just came across this post in fixing this same issue on my own machine, and here's some help if others are stuck. (Ubuntu 14.04).

libatlas-dev does NOT have libatlas-base-dev as a dependency! Caffe seems to like the libraries from the latter only. Install it.

Then, run the commands suggested by @Ran and select the libraries from the atlas-base directory under /usr/lib. With just libatlas-dev installed, update-alternatives will have the output at the bottom of @swalog's post, but does not actually link an atlas library that caffe seems to approve of! It needs to be the one from atlas-base. Hope this helps!